# How to store database values as comma separated?

Tags: php, javascript

here am trying to take the set of database values as comma separated and store it in a javascript variable. I tried doing it. but i couldnt make them comma separated as the output comes all together. Please correct me where am doing mistake.

Notes : If the value of assignedto is empty. the staff names with flag 1 will get fetched from database. but in the script below it comes all together where i require them to be comma separated.

```
 if(assignedto == "")
    {
    '<?php
        $val = mysql_query("select * from staff where flag='1'");
        $arr='';
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($val))
        {
        $arr = array($row['name']);
        $assign .= implode(',',$arr);

    ?>'
    assignedto = '<?php echo $assign; }?>';
    }
```

Comment: Please post an example of the output you expect. You are selecting multiple columns (presumably), but only accessing the `name` column in your loop.

Comment: There is an error in your code so your javascript shouldn't run at all. You shouldn't enclose <?php ... ?> in quotations like that ' .

Comment: now the value of assignedto is coming something like johnjacobsara i want it to be john,jacob,sara

Comment: am trying to fetch from  column(name) where log is an another column and am tryin to fetch name where the log value is 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, but you code seems to be wrong, have you tried this?

```
if(assignedto == ""){
   <?php
   $val = mysql_query("select * from staff where flag='1'");
   $arr=array();
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($val)){
       $arr[] = $row['name'];
   }
   $assign = implode(',',$arr);
   ?>
   assignedto = '<?php echo str_replace('\'','\\\'',$assign); ?>';
}
```

Comment: You should always use `json_encode` when passing data from PHP to JavaScript: `assignedto = <?php echo json_encode($assign); ?>;`

Comment: Yep you are right, but user does not want to create an structure, he just wants to have the comma separated string, but of course, to be sure that produced code is js valid, I have added str_replace for appostrophes

Comment: :) I need exactly this: *More information about this error may be available in the server error log*

Comment: you sdhouldn't need the `array()` around `$row['name']`. Just use `$arr[]= $row['name'];`

Comment: @Bala. C I have made few amendmends, can you check it one more time?